# the use of 園地（えんち）、庭（にわ）

Tags: word-choice

I have problem with word use again:)
there are these two words 園地 (enchi) and 庭 (niwa)。
as far as I know 'niwa' refers to a garden around the house right?
What about 'enchi' does it refer to a house garden as well or maybe to the garden of a shrine or temple?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7):

園地 is more like a park or garden (in the sense that the word garden is sometimes used for public parks in English). It definitely doesn't have to be on a temple or shrine grounds. Check out Higashi Yuuenchi (東遊園地) in Kobe for example: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%B1%E9%81%8A%E5%9C%92%E5%9C%B0

Comment: Thank you for the help. oh right yuuenchi:) I have met this word before:) yuuenchi is amusement park right? so in a "yuuenchi" there are means of amusements and a simple 'enchi' might be a place with trees and benches. sorry if I mix it totally.:)

Comment: Yes, 遊園地 is an amusement park. A lot of people also use the word テーマパーク as well, especially for a place that has, well, a theme - cultural, historical and movie related are very popular.